# Sparks when wiring a plug

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I turned off the breakers to
The garage but I guess I still had power to the bad gfci that I was replacing. At the end of the install the ground wire touched the hot wire and sparked. The breaker did not trip but I have tried resetting it numerous times to no avail. None of my other garage plugs have power now even with the breaker turned on. I have done the wiggle test on them all and used a receptacle tester on them all and they don’t have power. Any advice? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Where was the breaker(s) you turned off to try cut off power to the garage: In a subpanel in the garage or in the main panel feeding a garage subpanel?

Comment: It was the main panel. I’m not aware of any sub panels.

Comment: Have you flipped all the breakers on all your panels? (Even the ones that don’t look tripped.)

Comment: Yes I have. There are 4 plugs currently not working in the garage. I cannot locate a tripped gfci anywhere other than the one I was replacing when I potentially caused a short.

Comment: I’d look at outlet(s) between the one you were working on and the panel. You might find a cooked/loose wire. Don’t forget to look outside.

Comment: One reason to double check there is no power when working on stuff.  Good chance you did not turn off the right breaker/s and were working with live power all the time.  Just good luck you did not strip a hot wire with your teeth.

Comment: Get back to basics.  Do you have power to any of the black wires on the GFCI you were changing?   Do you know that resetting a breaker require that it be turned to the "off" position, then back to "on"?  Can you post a pick of the wires in the box of the GFCI youare changing.